# python doesn't connect mysql. pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Tags: python, pymysql

I connect mysql with pymysql. but below error raise

```
pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password="pass", db='db_name', charset='utf8', port=3306)
```

pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

So I check my root password. But Through "mysql -u root -p" I login in mysql.
and I execute "grant all privileges on [db_name] to root@localhost;". but it's same. 
Also i execute "grant all privileges on [db_name] to root@localhost identified by "Password". but error raise "

error : "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by 'password'' at line 1

Comment: if you've set root password to Password  (`.. identified by "Password"`), 
then pass this one as connection parameter for password. i mean, `pymysql.connect(host=..., user=.., password='Password', ...)`

Comment: sorry. i set same password. it's typo

Comment: It should be:  "grant all privileges on [db_name] to 'root'@'localhost';" 
Note the quotes around root and localhost. Are you connecting to a remote database ?

Answer (score 0):

What version of MySQL are you using? I was not able to use PyMySQL with MySQL 8, so I had to downgrade to 5.4.

**EDIT:** Here's my thread on troubleshooting and ultimately resolving: [PyMySQL Access Denied "using password (no") but using password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336458/pymysql-access-denied-using-password-no-but-using-password)